# Copy paste not working using Robot Class: Ctrl+C; content is not saving into clipboard, but it used to work perfectly fine few days back

Tags: java, selenium, sdk

```
    *
```

Basically i've selected some text and trying to copy it; but below code is not doing Ctrl+C during runtime-nothing is storing into clipboard-however manually i've tried my keys are working fine, but it used to work few days back. Could you please help me on this issue.

```
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);

*
```

Answer (score 0):

> First you need to release the key "C" and then "Control" key.

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
Thread.sleep(2000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
Thread.sleep(2000);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
Thread.sleep(2000);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```